# How to ensure that my page is wrapped by operamini browser?

Tags: html, css, opera, nokia-s40, opera-mini

I am developing page for low end phones like s40. However, I also need to make sure it works on phone with bigger screen. My page loads fine on bigger screen but its behavior is random with opera mini in nokia s40 phones. Sometimes the page is wrapped around properly, which is what I want. But other times I have to zoom, which is absolutely not wanted. And this occurs without making any changes on my html or css file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to take a look on the device specific [mediaqueries here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) and also test your mobile browser or viewports compatibility on **Opera mobile emulator** , you can download it from Opera dev website..